# Unsupported node namespace: http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v2.0.0

Tags: java, transactions, osgi, blueprint-osgi, apache-servicemix

I'm seeing this error, when deploying a `bundle` that has some  `javax.transaction.Transactional` annotations

```
Unsupported node namespace: http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v2.0.0
```

What I don't understand is that the bundle does reach the `Active` state, what's even weirder is that transactions work (rolling back in case of error)

relevant information with regards to the `transaction` feature :

```
feature:info transaction
Feature transaction 1.3.0
Description:
   OSGi Transaction Manager
Details:
   JTA implementation provided by Apache Aries Transaction
Feature configuration:
   org.apache.aries.transaction
Feature has no configuration files
Feature depends on:
   transaction-api [1.1,2)
Feature contains followed bundles:
   mvn:org.apache.aries/org.apache.aries.util/1.1.1
   mvn:org.apache.aries.transaction/org.apache.aries.transaction.manager/1.3.0
Feature contains followed conditionals:
Conditional(aries-blueprint) has no configuration
Conditional(aries-blueprint) has no configuration files
Conditional(aries-blueprint) has no dependencies.
Conditional(aries-blueprint) contains followed bundles:
  mvn:org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.coordinator/1.0.2
  mvn:org.apache.aries.transaction/org.apache.aries.transaction.blueprint/1.1.1
  mvn:org.apache.aries.transaction/org.apache.aries.transaction.blueprint/2.1.0
```

Any help is much appreciated

EDIT 1

doing a `service:list | grep namespace | grep -i transaction` gives :

```
osgi.service.blueprint.namespace =   http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.2.0
osgi.service.blueprint.namespace = http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.0.0
osgi.service.blueprint.namespace = http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v1.1.0
osgi.service.blueprint.namespace = http://aries.apache.org/xmlns/transactions/v2.0.0
```

So as you can see, there is a handler for `transactions/v2.0.0`

EDIT 2

full stack trace : 
http://pastebin.com/raw/HWUQVJhS

thank you

Comment: Can you give a full exception stack trace?

Comment: I just added the stack trace

Comment: I met this issue during a project a couple of months ago in a project, too. The version 2.0.0 of the NameSpacehandler was not registered randomly. I debugged the code of blueprint a lot, but I could not find out the real cause. I guess it is related to some multi-threaded issue within the code of Aries-Blueprint.

Comment: Blueprint normally waits for the namespaces before starting up. So theoretically this issue should not happen. I guess somehow the namespace is unregistered while blueprint is parsing the file. Might be a bundle refresh issue. Can you open an issue in the Apache Aries jira?

Comment: Balazs Zsoldos, yes, for me too this problem occurs randomly

Comment: Christian Schneider, I'll get to the ticket, as soon as possible

Comment: But do you have an idea why the bundle still starts and works ? it is that once the handler is registered (after the exception is thrown)the bundle starts ?